# Ethereum web wallet for Tor

Tags: metamask, wallets, anonymity, tor

Can Metamask wallet ethereum addresses be created in the Tor browser, given that Metamask is a browser extension? If not, what web wallet is most appropriate for Tor users, especially on a WindowsPC running the Tails OS which deletes itself and all traces of the session upon shutdown?

Under Tails and  Tor, it seems the wallet would constantly have to be recovered because of each session being cleared, although this wouldn't really be an issue as long as the wallet only needs to be accessed seldom, since activity can be monitored on etherscan independent of Tor